# Make query to retrieve countries of each continent Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code (which works) that makes me able to retrieve all the countries of a specific continent:

```
 DatabaseReference paisNomeContinentes = mDatabase.child("continentes").child(Constants.PAISES_EUROPA).child("Paises");             // C1 - ÁFRIA        (Constants.PAISES_AFRICA)
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener1 = new ValueEventListener() {                                                          // C2 - ÁSIA         (Constants.PAISES_ASIA)
        @Override                                                                                                               // C3 - ANTÁRTIDA    (Constants.PAISES_ANTARTIDA)
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                                                                   // C4 - AMÉRICA      (Constants.PAISES_AMERICA)
            List<String> nomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();                                                                     // C5 - EUROPA       (Constants.PAISES_EUROPA)
                                                                                                                               // C6 - OCEANIA      (Constants.PAISES_OCEANIA)
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String nomePais = ds.child("Nome").getValue(String.class);
                nomePaisList.add(nomePais);
            }

            int urlCount = nomePaisList.size();
            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(urlCount);
            List<String> randomNomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
                randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber));
                txtHomeDesc.setText(randomNomePaisList.get(i)); // Inserir na TextView o nome do respetivo país
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    paisNomeContinentes.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener1);
```

And this is the structure of my `Firebase Realtime Database` for this code:

[image]

I created this structure for testing. I ended up using this instead:

[image]

The problem is, the code I have doesn't work for this structure. How can I retrieve the countries which have the `Continente = Europa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a query:

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference paisNomeContinentes = mDatabase.getReference().child("paises");             
Query queries=paisNomContinentes.orderByChild("Continente").equalTo("Europa");
queries.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener1);
```

The snapshot is at child `paises` then using the query you will be able to retrieve the data that has Continente=Europa

Comment: After that I do a `for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())`, am I right?